# force getting gps location

Tags: java, android, gps, locationmanager

I'm searching about some code to force my app to get GPS location quickly ASAP

i don't wanna to use INTERNET or cell , i want to get GPS faster as possible

is there is any code to do that ? or just waiting gps to pick points from 
location manager ?

my code :

```
   public class StoPoints extends ListActivity implements LocationListener
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, this);

    @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location2) {
    location = location2; 
}
```

Comment: `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` often takes time to get the first satellite fix, plus you need to be outdoor for this to work as your device needs a clear view of the sky in order to locate the satellites circling above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there is any code to do that ? or just waiting gps to pick points from location manager ?

The code you have is as fast as it is going to get. How quickly you get GPS fixes is dependent upon a number of things, including device and the general environment (e.g., can you receive signals from enough satellites?).

Comment: what about usint laskKnownLocation ? is this get more fast ?

Comment: see : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Comment: @user3245658: `getLastKnownLocation()` does precisely what the method says. It gets the last known location, if there is one, for the provider. This returns almost immediately. However, you may get `null`, and you may get a location that is wrong (because GPS has not been turned on recently and the user moved).